# php simple html dom get a href id inside td

Tags: php, html, dom, find, href

How to grab "name" or "id" attribute inside a href using php simple html dom. Also I need "title text" inside "h4" tag.
Could you please help me?
Here is the html:

```
<td>
<a href="../Vehicle?itemID=22995061&RowNumber=9&loadRecent=True" name="22995061" id="22995061">
<h4>title text</h4>
</a>
<p>
Stock#:
<text>example</text>
</p>
<p>BLA BLA</p>
<p> fffff  </p>
</td>
```

I tried something like this, but it returns me blank.

```
IDs = array();  
    $url = "http://someurl";
    $html = file_get_html(url);
foreach($html->find('h4') as $e)
 {

     echo $e->innertext."<br>";
     $dataID = $e->innertext; 
     $IDs[] = $dataID; 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, change,

```
IDs = array();
```

to,

```
$IDs = array();
```

Then, why don't you make use of the [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class rather than a regex. Simply load your DOM and then use [`getElementsByTagName`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) to get your tags. This way you can exclude any other tags which you don't want and only get those that you do.

**Example**

```
<?php
$xml = <<< XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<books>
 <book>Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture</book>
 <book>Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Software Design</book>
 <book>Clean Code</book>
</books>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$books = $dom->getElementsByTagName('book');
foreach ($books as $book) {
    echo $book->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
}
?>
```

**Reading Material**

[`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: Hi, tnx for the reply, but I'm using php simple html dom to grab data, because I'm behind proxy. I don't know how to use php DOM to grab url when I'm behind proxy server.